# Multiple Exchange Accounts - Change Deleted Items Folder

Tags: microsoft-outlook, exchange

Good Morning!

I have a user that manages a couple of different Exchange accounts from her Outlook 2010 front end.  Currently, when she deletes an item from the secondary exchange account, it goes into the deleted items folder in her primary exchange account.

Exchange 2 deletes item, goes to Exchange 1 trash

She would like it to be:

Exchange 2 deletes item, goes to Exchange 2 trash while maintaining Exchange 1 deletes item, goes to Exchange 1 trash.

I have looked into the rules and settings for it, as well as googling the problem to not much avail.

Anyone have an idea if this is doable?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the way the secondary account is configured. It has to be added as a second account, not as an additional Exchange mailbox in the primary account properties.

Also, check MS KB202517: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/202517

Comment: Confirmed that the account is added as a secondary account under the primary > Open These Additional Mailboxes.  Thanks for the link, looking into that as a solution now.

Comment: Confirmed that the "fix it for me" in the link you sent fixed the behavior.  Thanks for helping make one of my users happy!